# .NET library like gephi

Tags: c#, graph, analysis

I want to know if there is some .net controls like gephi : http://gephi.org/
I want to show a comparison between some species in biology (may be 10 000).

Comment: this might help you: http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: may be I have to search about networking graph,social network,there is some examples in web but with js or html5... this is a simple example http://www.anchormodeling.com/modeler/test/